# What do you call a second try at a test?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

At uni you can do the final test of a course twice, what do you call the second test ?

Is it a second term ? No that's the second semester isn't it ?

Comment: In the UK, it is called `resit exam` and we usually say `to resit an exam` or `to retake an exam`. I think the latter sounds less formal.

Comment: It's a resit in Oz

Comment: @Nico how do you pronounce it ? re-zit or re-sit sit like sitting on a chair ?

Comment: @d'alar'cop Oz ?

Comment: As in chair. Oz is short for Australia.

Comment: re-sit (it never occurred to me it could be to pronounced as re-zit, but I'm not a native speaker). I've just looked it up in the [Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/resit) and the pronunciation is /riːˈsɪt/.

Comment: @Nico me neither, I just read for the first time with a z, probably because it starts like resolution which is pronounced with a z.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you fail you might have the option to retake an exam (also used as a noun). In British English resit is also (more?) commonly used (both as verb and noun).

In some cases they are also called supplementary exams however these can also mean exams in other subjects or from a different exam board that can replace the original exam

Edit: retest is another possibility (from comments)

Comment: So in the US it's just called to retake the exam ? Is there no special word for it ?

Comment: i'm mainly a BE user but at least CS related certifications (which are always AME) always talk about retakes (which, as an afterthought, makes sense, since you take an exam or sit for an exam)

Comment: Microsoft uses "second shot" for their certification exams :)

Comment: @oerkelens true but they have an "exam retake policy" in their T&Cs :)

Comment: True, I just added it as an alternative expression :)

Comment: @GinKin The opportunity to take a final exam a second time is in no way universal in the U.S., and could depend not only on the university system, institution, academic unit, and academic department, but on the particular instructor. I am not surprised that there is no more specific term than *retest* or *retake*.

Comment: I have always heard it called a 're-test'

Comment: In the UK, it is normally called a *retake*.

Comment: @Tristanr A quick search confirms that, for instance, Oxford, Cambridge, Edinburgh and London Universities all call them resits. I'm sure they are also called retakes at some places - these things are usually regional/dialectal. Which one is the most popular is probably out of scope for this question.

Comment: During my time in the education system, they were normally called *retakes*. This may vary in different parts of the UK and, in different establishments. I would not consider Oxford, Cambridge, Edinburgh and London Universities to be typical of the education system throughout the UK, including schools and sixth forms, which also use the word *retakes*.

Comment: @Tristanr do you consider [edexel](http://www.edexcel.com/iwantto/Pages/resits.aspx) (admittedly uses resits as noun but retake as verb), [aqa](http://www.aqa.org.uk/exams-administration/dates-and-timetables) (uses re-sit) or [the bbc](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/education-20266533) typical? As I said, this is regional, and some schools surely use retake, but resit is definitely common.

Comment: Even the edexel link is inconsistent. Not only does the particular word used seem to vary in different parts of the country and different establishments but, *resit* seems to have become more common since my time in the education system, which was not such a long time ago.